# How is a done button added to a keyboard

Tags: iphone, uitextview, iphone-softkeyboard

I have a keyboard which edits text in a UITextView and tapping the return key doenst dismiss the keyboard, it only moves down to the next line.

How can I add a done button and make that dismiss the keyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement the

```
textView:shouldChangeTextInRange
```

method to look for "\n" then call

`resignFirstResponder` on the `textView` if it is found.

[Reference](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-dismiss-the-keyboard-when-using-a-uitextview.html)

Comment: Had to link the delegates in IB :)